printing out sql database information on popup
I want that when I press a button in my app it displays a popup which prints out info from database.(table is selected trough button).
class ThirdWindow(Screen):

    db_handler = DatabaseHandler()
    def display_database_info(self, query):
        cursor = self.db_handler.conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in results:
            print(row)  
        cursor.close()


this is how I printed out results in terminal.


\<ThirdWindow\>:

    name: "third"
    
    FloatLayout:
        
        size:root.width, root.height
    
        Button:
            text: "Pekarski proizvodi"
            font_size: self.width * 0.13
            size_hint: (0.1, 0.2)
            pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "y":0.3}
            on_release:
                query = "SELECT * FROM PekarskiProizvodi"
                root.display_database_info(query)


and this is the button that you click to display


----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class ThirdWindow(Screen):

    db_handler = DatabaseHandler()
    def display_database_info(self, query):
        cursor = self.db_handler.conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in results:
            print(row)  
        cursor.close() 


<ThirdWindow>:
name: "third"

FloatLayout:
    
    size:root.width, root.height

    Button:
        text: "Pekarski proizvodi"
        font_size: self.width * 0.13
        size_hint: (0.1, 0.2)
        pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "y":0.3}
        on_release:
            query = "SELECT * FROM PekarskiProizvodi"
            root.display_database_info(query)

MyPopup@Popup
auto_dismiss: False
size_hint: 0.6, 0.2
post_hint: {"x":0.2, "y":0.9}
title: "Pekarski proizvodi"

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        id: PekarskiProizvodi
        text: ""
    Button: 
        text: "Zatvori"
        fontsize: 10
        on_release: root.dismiss()

AND  I want this popup to display the information from database
